# Accessing transformer functions in `sklearn` pipelines

Tags: python, scikit-learn

According to [sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html) documentation,

> The pipeline has all the methods that the last estimator in the pipeline has, i.e. if the last estimator is a classifier, the Pipeline can be used as a classifier. If the last estimator is a transformer, again, so is the pipeline.

The following example creates a dummy transformer with a custom, dummy function `f`:

```
class C:
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        print('fit')
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        print('transform')
        return X

    def f(self):
        print('abc')

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
ppl = Pipeline([('C', C())])
```

I was expecting to be able to access the `f` function of the `C` transformer, however calling `ppl.f()` results in `AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'f'`

Am I misinterpreting the documentation? Is there a good and reliable way to access the last transformer's functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Pipeline` documentation slightly overstates things. It has all the *estimator* methods of its last estimator. These include things like `predict(), fit_predict(), fit_transform(), transform(), decision_function(), predict_proba()...`.

It cannot use any other functions, because it wouldn't know what to do with all the other steps in the pipeline. For most situations, you pass `(X)` or possibly `(X,y)`, and X and/or y must pass through every chain in the pipeline either with `fit_transform()` or `transform()`.

It is fairly easy to access the last estimator, like this:

```
ppl.steps[-1][1].f()
```

But remember that doing so is bypassing the previous steps in the pipeline (i.e., if you pass it `X`, it won't be scaled with your StandardScaler or whatever you are doing earlier in the pipeline.)